# JqGrid server side query conflicts with search

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

Take a look at my grid;
[image: grid]
The last column reviewed returns tiny int value (0 or 1) from a MySQL database. What I am trying to achieve is to only display the rows where ***reviewed = 0*** and still be able to use search to perform query and retrieve fields where ***reviewed = 1***. I want to display rows where ***reviewed =0*** when the grid initially loads. I have tried to do this server side   using code like `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE reviewed = 0"`. In this case the query works but the search does not work. Is there a way to do this on the client? Please help I have been on this problem for days. I have tried almost everything.

```
Here's my server side code;
//Get the requested page
$page = $_GET['page'];

//Get how many rows we want to have into the grid
$limit = $_GET['rows'];

// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;

//array to translate the search type
$ops = array(
    'eq'=>'=', //equal
    'ne'=>'<>',//not equal
    'lt'=>'<', //less than
    'le'=>'<=',//less than or equal
    'gt'=>'>', //greater than
    'ge'=>'>=',//greater than or equal
    'bw'=>'LIKE', //begins with
    'bn'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't begin with
    'in'=>'LIKE', //is in
    'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', //is not in
    'ew'=>'LIKE', //ends with
    'en'=>'NOT LIKE', //doesn't end with
    'cn'=>'LIKE', // contains
    'nc'=>'NOT LIKE'  //doesn't contain
);
function getWhereClause($col, $oper, $val){
    global $ops;
    if($oper == 'bw' || $oper == 'bn') $val .= '%';
    if($oper == 'ew' || $oper == 'en' ) $val = '%'.$val;
    if($oper == 'cn' || $oper == 'nc' || $oper == 'in' || $oper == 'ni') $val = '%'.$val.'%';
    return " WHERE $col {$ops[$oper]} '$val' ";
}
$where = ""; //if there is no search request sent by jqgrid, $where should be empty
$searchField = isset($_GET['searchField']) ? $_GET['searchField'] : false;
$searchOper = isset($_GET['searchOper']) ? $_GET['searchOper']: false;
$searchString = isset($_GET['searchString']) ? $_GET['searchString'] : false;
if ($_GET['_search'] == 'true') {
    $where = getWhereClause($searchField,$searchOper,$searchString);
  }

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM renal_apptRequest"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$count = $row['count']; 

// calculate the total pages for the query 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
              $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
              $total_pages = 0; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 
  $SQL = "SELECT * FROM renal_apptRequest".$where." ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error());
```

Here's my client side code

```
$(function () {
               $("#list").jqGrid({
            url:"grid_apptRequest.php",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "GET",
            colNames:["ID","Date","referralType","patientName","patientAddress","patientDOB","referralProvider","referralReason","contactName","contactPhone","contactEmail","contactFax","preferredTime","comments","reviewed"],
            colModel: [
        { name: "id",index:'id', width: 55,search:true, formatter:'showlink',formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'renal_apptRequest_review.php', target:'_blank'}},
        { name: "date",index:'date',search:true, width: 90 },
        { name: "referralType",index:'referralType',search:true, width: 80},
        { name: "patientName",index:'patientName',search:true, width: 120},
        { name: "patientAddress",index:'patientAddress',search:true, width: 120},
        { name: "patientDOB",index:'patientDOB',search:true, width: 90 },
        { name: "referralProvider",index:'referralProvider',search:true, width: 90 },
        { name: "referralReason",index:'referralReason',search:true, width: 120 },
        { name: "contactName",index:'contactName',search:true, width: 100},
        { name: "contactPhone",index:'contactPhone',search:true, width: 100},
        { name: "contactEmail",index:'contactEmail',search:true, width: 100 },
        { name: "contactFax",index:'contactFax',search:true, width: 80},
        { name: "preferredTime",index:'preferredTime',search:true, width: 70 },
        { name: "comments",index:'comments',search:true, width: 100 },
        { name: "reviewed",index:'reviewed',search:true,hidedlg:true, width: 60, align: "right" }
    ],
        pager: "#pager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10,20,30],
        autowidth:true,
        sortname: "id",
        sortorder: "asc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        caption: "Appointment Request",

        afterInsertRow: function (id, currentData, jsondata) {
     if(currentData.reviewed == 1){ 
            $('#list').jqGrid('delRowData',id);
  }

}
            }).navGrid("#pager", {search:true, edit:false,add:false,del:false,searchtext:"Search"});
```

Here's an example of JSON data that populates my grid. This is done on the server side. $cipher->decryptThis() is a decryption algorithm used to decrypt encrypted fields from the database.

```
$responce = new stdClass();
$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages;
$responce->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['id'],$row['date'],$row['referralType'],$cipher->decryptThis($row['patientName']),$cipher->decryptThis($row['patientAddress']),$cipher->decryptThis($row['patientDOB']),$row['referralProvider'], $cipher->decryptThis($row['referralReason']),$cipher->decryptThis($row['contactName'])
    ,$cipher->decryptThis($row['contactPhone']),$cipher->decryptThis($row['contactEmail']), $row['contactFax'],$row['preferredTime'],$row['comments'], 
    $row['reviewed']  );
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($responce);
```

Comment: So you don't want to display rows when reviewed > 0 ? Is that correct?

Comment: Reviewed can only be 1 0r 0 and yes I don't want to display a row when reviewed = 1.

Comment: Slightly confused by this statement  > SELECT * FROM table WHERE reviewed = 0 (query works, but search fails). Do you mean to say search fails when you choose the review column as search critera?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE reviewed = 0 works. Search does not work at all for any of the columns with that query. And I would like to be able to choose reviewed = 1 as search criteria. Please take a peep at the code above. Thanks

Comment: So why can't you just take the where clause you have constructed in $where for the search and add " AND reviewed = 0" or " AND reviewed = 1" to the end ?

Comment: That's because the getWhereClause() is used to conduct the search query. I don't want to restrict search to reviewed = 0. I only want to restrict the original data returned from the database. But on doing this with SELECT * FROM table WHERE reviewed = 0, the search does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a php expert. My expertise is jqgrid. In jqgrid you can do this via a hack using the **afterinsertRow event**. In your code add the following. This will remove rows which has got **reviewed = 1**

```
    caption: "Appointment Request",
    afterInsertRow: function (id, currentData, jsondata) {

      if(currentData.reviewed == '1'){ 
         // I am not sure if reviewed is string or number. If the above 
         // doesn't work try currentData.reviewed == 1 
        $('#list').jqGrid('delRowData',id);
      }

    },
```

Your php code looks a bit fiddly. Some tweaking there might help you to achieve it there, but as a I said I am not a php expert so I can't guarantee that. But the above code definitely does the trick.

[What does afterInsertRow does:](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents)

- This event fires after every inserted row.
- rowid is the id of the inserted row
- rowdata is an array of the data to be inserted into the row. This is array of type name: value, where the name is a name from colModel
- rowelem is the element from the response. If the data is xml this is the xml element of the row; if the data is json this is array containing all the data for the row
- Note: this event does not fire if gridview option is set to true

Comment: I tested in my local machine and it works perfectly (though the data is different). Can you please update your question with the latest client side code. Also it would be great if you could post part of your json as well.

Comment: I have just updated the question with new client side code and JSON. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Can you try puttign a breakpoint in below two lines:                  >>if(currentData.reviewed == 1){ 
>>            $('#list').jqGrid('delRowData',id);
Regarding Json - I was looking for the exact json string (Just a part of it, like one node)

Comment: I have found a way to do it you can mark my answer below. Thanks it works great too.

Comment: But from your code above I still have a few questions. What triggers the afterInsertRow event. Maybe if there was an event that occurs on page load the code could actually work.

Comment: See my update in the answer - "What does afterInsertRow does". Did you put a break point in that afterInsertRow and let me know if control comes inside it. If that doesn't work, your question is wrong or you have described the question correctly.

Comment: It worked when i removed gridView = true. When i search for rows where reviewed = 1 it comes back empty because delRowData has been initiated on rows where reviewed = 1. Is there a function I can call to fix this any way at all.

Comment: Is there a way to use filter to solve this problem without asking the user to perform any action.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to group the data by the field of interest in my case ***reviewed***. This snippet of code does the trick. Insert it before the caption of your grid.

```
grouping:true,
            groupingView : {
            groupField : ['reviewed'],
            groupColumnShow : [true],
            groupText:['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>'],
            groupCollapse : true,
            groupOrder: ['desc']
            },
```